# Поиск в отношениях Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
User::with('comments')
       ->whereHas('comments', function ($query){
          $query->where('id', '>', 10);})
       ->get();
```

Подскажите, нужно вернуть всех пользователей и показать их комментарии с `id > 10`, но в моем случае получаю всех юзеров с `id > 10`, как исправить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неправильно составлен запрос.

Данный запрос вернет **всех** пользователей и комментарии к ним если у них `id > 10`.

```
User::with([
    'comments'=> function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '>', 10);
    }
])->get();
```

А `whereHas` вернет **только тех** пользователей где у комментария `id > 10`.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста еще, к примеру есть таблица где хранится информация каким пользователям какие комментарии можно смотреть user_id и comment_id как в вашем примере отсортировать какие комментарии показать зная залогининого юзера

Comment: @Васили, Не понятна суть вопроса.
Несколько пользователей могут смотреть чужой комментарий?
Или вернуть комментарии для **конкретного** (залогиненого) пользователя?

Comment: Смотрите, в вашем примере мы получаем всех пользователей и выводим в каждом пользователе их комментарии где id > 10, мне нужно то же самое но у нас есть таблица где храниться какой комментарий может прочитать пользователь, к примеру залогинненый пользователь Василий может просматривать комментарий с id = 1, 10,22 и ему показываем всех пользователей но комментарии к ним показываем только с id = 1, 10,22

Comment: Почитайте про **hasManyThrough**. Точно не скажу как решить, все зависит от архитектуры ДБ и др.